# Symfony2: adding form fields dynamically using information from request

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Scenario:

1. step 1: fetch information from some archaic web service
2. step 2: adding x radio buttons to my form, while x depends on the information from the web service

I understand that I should add an Event Subscriber Class as shown [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class)

$event has a setData method. Probably I have to use it. How can I access this method from the controller?

Additional information:
I am using Doctrine. At the moment I am creating a Doctrine entity and pass this to the form like this:

```
$product = new Product(); $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to setData() on the $event object. You've to implement an [`on POST_SET_DATA`](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/FormEvents.php) logic that builds your form [the way you want](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#inside-the-event-subscriber-class) according to you data.

You've then to initialize your form (inside your controller) using your webservice's reply.

(**Note:** SET_DATA form event is deprecated since version 2.1. It'll be definitely removed in version 2.3)

**Update:**

You can set an array as form data and use a `DataTransformer` to structure your form's data the way you want. Take a look at the [Data Transformation part](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAX13g5orwo&feature=share&list=PLo7mBDsRHu11ChvScWUE7MN1Qo5QVHQEz) of [Symfony 2 Form Tricks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAX13g5orwo&feature=share&list=PLo7mBDsRHu11ChvScWUE7MN1Qo5QVHQEz) during the last San Francisco Symfony Live.

Comment: At the moment I am initializing my doctrine entity and then passing it. <pseudo code>: `$product = new Product(); $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);`. Is the right approach to add pseudo attributes to the product entity, set them using the information from the web services and pass this extended  product entity?

Comment: @jamie0726 So your form use a product object + extra fields he get through the web service, right?

Comment: exactly :-) The user selects one of those extra options which will be stored in the database as "normal" entity attribute.

Comment: This is a great talk, thanks for linking it though Bernhard says that DataTransformers are not supposed to use for dynamic form events only for transformation between view, normalized and (forgot the third on) data model. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @jamie0726 Exactly, I think you could just use a Data Transformer to format your data ($product + extra fields) in order to keep your code clean. There's no real need to manage it through events I think.

Comment: I figured something out using EventListeners and added it as a potential solution...

Comment: additional note: Bernhard says in his talk that one should never modify the content of data in Data Transformers, that's why I came back to EventListeners... quite complex for a rather simple task... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution I ended up with. Not sure if this is the best way, so this answer is not marked as correct to encourage other, more experience Symfony  user to come up with a better solution.

What I don't like about this solution, is that I cannot pass my whole product entity to the form any more, but have to add each attribute individually to the options array:

Anyway, that's how it is implemented now:

The dynamic data is passed using the options array as second parameter to createForm():

```
  // ExampleController.php

  use Acme\ExampleBundle\Entity\Product;
  public function addAction()
  {
     // choices contains the dynamic data I am fetching from the webservice in my actual code
     $choices = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");

     // now create a new Entity
     $product = new Product();

     // and some attributes already have values for some reason
     $product->setPrice(42);

     $form = $this->createForm(new AddproductType(), 
              array(
                 "choices" => $choices,
                 "price"   => $product->getPrice() 
               )
            );
     if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
          // ... standard symfony stuff here
        }
     }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
 }
```

And now for the form class. Note the event listener part and the setDefaultOptions method.

```
// ProductType.php

namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class ProductType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory) {

                // get the option array passed from the controller
                $options = $event->getData();

                $choices = $options["choices"];
                $event->getForm()->add(
                // add a new element with radio buttons to the form
                $formFactory->createNamed("my_dynamic_field_name", "choice", null, array(
                        "empty_value" => "Choose an option",
                        "label" => "My dynamic field: ",
                        "choices" => $choices
                    )
                )
            );

        }
    );

    // ... add other form elements
    $builder->add("price", "text");
    // ..
 }

 public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
 {
    // register choices as a potential option
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'choices' => null
    ));
 }
}
```